# Change access modifier of type when using "Add as Link" in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio I can add an existing file to a solution by using the "Add as Link". A link is then added to the project and refers to the original file, thus I only have one copy of the file. This is sometimes necessary because including another assembly as reference is not possible, e.g. source generators or build tasks.

The problem is that the linked files contains some classes that have a predefined access modifier. But I need to change that. The project that links to the file should make the access modifier private.

Is this possible? I already checked some project settings, but couldn't find a way.

Comment: I once see a solution that worked by using different symbols defined depends on the projects and `#if` pragma in the linked file that specified correct visibility depending on that. Not a pretty solution but worked.

Comment: That was also my idea, but I was hoping there is a better solution ;-)

Comment: Did you refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880609/how-to-use-generics-containing-private-types-with-visual-studio-unit-tests

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT. I don't think so. Its about having a linked file in my project with 

  <Compile Include="..\..\Core\ipipe.SourceGeneration.Utilities\*.cs" />

but I would understand that this is not possible since there can be multiple classes inside.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't seem to provide a built-in mechanism for modifying the access modifiers of individual classes in a single linked file. Paweł Łukasik's proposal is useful

Comment: Understood, I thought so. Thanks.